# how to give a role when a user reacts to a message?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that essentially gives a user a role when they react to a message. I've tried some code, but when I run the bot and react to a pre-sent message, no errors occur and nothing happens. Here's the code:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def reactionrole(ctx, emoji, *, role):
    roleEmbed = discord.Embed(title='Reaction Roles', description='React to this message with the proper emoji to give yourself the role.', color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 107, 33))
    roleEmbed.add_field(name='Roles & Emojis:', value=f'{emoji} = {role}', inline=True)
    message = await ctx.send(embed=roleEmbed)
    await message.add_reaction(f'{emoji}')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    Channel = client.get_channel('my id')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == "{emoji}":
      Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="event pings")
      await client.add_roles(user, Role)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `on_raw_reaction_add` or `client.wait_for` depending if you want the users to react to a message already sent in a channel a while back or for a message sent in a command

```py
@client.command()
async def reaction_role(ctx):
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction) == '✅'

    message = await ctx.send('Please react with ✅ to get the role')
    try:
        # Waiting for the reaction
        await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=60.0)
        await ctx.author.add_roles(some_role)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send('Time is over')
```

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == my_message_id: 
        guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.member_id)
        await member.add_roles(some_role)
```

Reference:

- [bot.wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)

Comment: I modified the code to the message id with quotes, and I replace some_role with my role name in quotes. All I got back was: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'"

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: also, the message id must be an integer, and the `some_role` variable must be a`discord.Role` object, not a string